# Add Facebook Photo Album to iOS6?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, photo-gallery

I'm very much out of it. I looked into Facebook Developer and it didn't have what I am looking for. 
I am making an iOS and Android app for a VBS program. I was wanting to add their official Facebook Photo Album to the app so when the user has wifi, they can view it after tapping a UITableView Cell.

I need advice on where to start. Is there a tutorial I have overlooked on Google that will show me what I need? I use App Inventor for Android. I use Xcode for iOS devices.

What I was wanting to do for this app is simple: Give people access of the Facebook Album for this event... it saves me space and makes it more pleasing to them. They cannot touch/modify anything in the album.

Danke!
-TG52

Comment: What do you mean their "official Facebook Photo Album"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a user or pages albums by the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) endpoint `PAGE_OR_USER_ID/albums`. Once you know what the album ID is, you can simply call `ALBUM_ID/photos`. This will return numerous `photo` objects, each with a `picture` and `source` properties.
 Play around in the [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to learn how the responses are formatted.

From here, you'll have the url and height and width of each photo. Build your UIView as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy Crush! I'm sorry it took a while to respond, this is very helpful!